# Delimiter concluded in text in some cells

Tags: c#, csv, delimiter, import-csv

I am making a Software which hast to read much data from a CSV file. The CSV file uses ';' as the delimiter. Recently I found out that the text in some cells also concludes ';'. Every tuple from the file is an Object and so every cell in this row is an Attribute of this Object. I use the method Split in C#, which returns an Array of Strings. Because  of the ';' in some cells I get an error: Array is out of bound. Are there some ways to get rid of this Error without removing the ';' from some cells?

Example for such a tuple:

Cell1;cell2;cell3;stillCell3;cell4;

Cell3;stillCell3 is one cell but the Split method does not know that.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Be very wary of reinventing the wheel - use https://www.nuget.org/packages/LumenWorksCsvReader/

Comment: Can you post a bit of the data? From your description, it sounds like there are just multiple ';' in a row which would be easy to deal with, but your example would be impossible to deal with.

Comment: @MineR No, it's my companies data

Comment: Then is your example how the data really appears? Or do you have something like Cell1;cell2;cell3;;cell4

Comment: @MineR yeah, for example. But the ; behind cell3 should belong to the text in cell3

Comment: Well there's no programmatic way of doing what you're asking. You've gotta manually clean your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original data does not meet the requirements of the CSV file format. No parser can deal with issues that humans would scratch their head about.

You cannot parse ambiguous values. You have to either escape delimiters in field values or have to put values between double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can escapes these values by embedding the field inside a set of double quotes. For more details you can refer this link

[CSV File Format](https://www.csvreader.com/csv_format.php)

**------------EDIT 1 ---------------------**

Consider this example. It is a comma separated `csv`

[image]

Here you can see a column "OK,123;asw.wew" with ',' and';'

If we open it with notepad or text editor we can see that it is automatically added escape character.

[image]

You have to code in such a way that it will split on separator not inside the double quotes.

**-------------------------- EDIT 2 --------------------------**

You can take advantage of `.net` class `TextFieldParser`.To use it

- add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` (yes, it says VisualBasic but it works in C# just as well)
- use the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` class to parse `CSV` file

Here is the sample code:

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"c:\test.csv"))
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters(",");
    while (!parser.EndOfData) 
    {
        //Processing row
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
        foreach (string field in fields) 
        {
            //TODO: Process field
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some more useful links:

- [MSDN: Read From Comma-Delimited Text Files in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx)
- [MSDN: TextFieldParser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx)

Comment: @user10024569 check the edit. Open your `.csv` in text editor and please share the data if possible

Comment: The CSV file has about 1000 lines that I would have to change

Comment: no in my case when i edited the cell in excel it automatically included the double quotes. can you check your csv by open it in text editor like notepad

Answer (score -1):

You can try [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) it has many options to read the fields.

```
using (TextFieldParser lcsvReader = new TextFieldParser(new MemoryStream(<FILE_BYTES>), Encoding.Default))
{
    lcsvReader.Delimiters = new string[2] { ",", "\t" };
    lcsvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
    lcsvReader.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
    while (!lcsvReader.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields = lcsvReader.ReadFields();
        //fields -- Actual field in CSV
    }
    lcsvReader.Close();
}
```